# Qual è il significato di "spuntare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> «What’s your name?», le chiese un maestro biondo. Vita evitò di guardarlo. Fissò il muro, con disgusto. C’era un quadretto, al centro del quale spiccava la faccia barbuta e solenne di un uomo. Il maestro tralasciò. Del resto, il nome della nuova arrivata – l’ennesima greenhorn del Mulberry District – poteva leggerlo nel registro. Iniziò a tracciare parole sulla lavagna. Erano parole americane. Vita non le capiva. Il maestro camminava fra i banchi. Gli altri bambini **spuntavano** le matite sui quaderni e alzavano la mano. Erano cinesi, irlandesi ed ebrei, ma parlavano tutti americano.

Ho letto il contenuto della voce ["spuntare" sul vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/spuntare1), ma non sono sicura di capirne il senso nel brano sopra citato. Significa che i bambini rompevano le punte delle matite sui quaderni?

Comment: Mi piacerebbe sapere la ragione del voto negativo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La tua intuizione è corretta e l'accezione di spuntare che si adatta al contesto da te citato è la seguente:

> 1. tr. a. Rompere la punta, **far perdere la punta a un oggetto acuminato**: *s. la penna, il temperino, le forbici*; come intr. pron.: *la matita, cadendo, s’è spuntata*;

Direi che più che rompere in questo caso il significato di spuntare sia quello di far perdere la punta ad un oggetto acuminato, in questo caso la matita.

I bambini spuntavano le matite calcando con forza sui quaderni e scrivendo veloci, quasi a rimarcare che loro conoscendo l'americano, a differenza di Vita, riuscivano a scrivere le parole velocemente consumando la punta della matita fino a privarla della punta.

Comment: In pratica, in questo caso è un sinonimo di "consumavano" :)

Comment: Esattamente, non le rompevano bruscamente ma spuntavano le matite scrivendo velocemente e calcando sul foglio.